# Why does the angle of a banked curve stay at 70-ish degrees past a certain velocity and radius value?

Tags: circular-motion

$$\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{\nu^2}{rg} - \mu}{1 + \frac{\mu \nu^2}{rg}} \right)$$

I entered the formula above into a python code and ran it to:

Starting at 1, increase the velocity and radius by 1 and give out an answer for each iteration.

I found that past a certain point the angle gets to 73 or 74 degrees and doesn't increase much further than this.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZVxW.png)

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The limiting angle depends on the value of $\mu$. As $v\to\infty$ (and I guess you're having $r\to\infty$ also, with $r=v$), the quantity inside the fraction approaches $1/\mu$, so $\theta$ approaches $\tan^{-1}(1/\mu)$.